# Pass data on POST method without input fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

I have a service where I have passed the data without input field. I have a JSON response and I have take nthe required data from JSON response and passed it on an API call with the method `POST`.

On click of the button "Book" (as in the uploaded picture), I have sent `doctorId` and `time`.

Form the input field, I know, but without input tag I don't know.

Here is my code.

Service.js

```
newbooking : function(data) {
    var param = angular.toJson(data, false);
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: server + '/Bookings',
        data: param,
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
    });
},
```

HTML code:

```
<ion-list id = "background"  ng-controller = "CliniclistCtrl">
    <div id = "background"  ng-repeat="available in appointment.Appointments"  >
      <ion-item class="item-stable item item-avatar" ng-click = "select(available.DoctorId);">
        <img ng-src = "img/1.png"/>
        <!--  &nbsp; -->
        {{available.Name}}
        &nbsp;
        <p>{{available.Speciality}}</p>
        </ion-item  >
         <ion-item class="item-accordion"
                ng-repeat="item in available.Appointments"
                ng-show="isSelected(available.DoctorId)">
        <a>{{item.AppointmentTime}} <br/> Available: {{item.Available}} </br>Doctor Id: {{available.DoctorId}}</a>
        <button style = "float : right; width:100px; font-size: 15px; border-radius: 8px; border-color: #66cc33;" class="button button-small button-balanced" ng-click = "book();">Book</button>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
```

Please tell me how can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the parameters into your booking function, like this:

```
<button ng-click="book(item.AppointmentTime, avalaible.DoctorID)">Book</button>
```

In your controller you will do:

```
$scope.book = function(time,id){
    //call your service here.
    newbooking(time,id);
}
```